# What is the best keyboard button setting you use to run fast in Assassin's Creed?

Tags: keyboard, assassins-creed-2

I just started playing "Assassin's Creed". It's confusing me. I'm at the beginning, I have to run fast and win the race with one guy, but it's difficult to press 2 buttons at the same time and then also manage the direction and walking buttons. Am I doing it wrong or is running really dependent on pressing two buttons at the same time?

Can you please tell me what a good combination or key mapping will make running easier for me?

Comment: I've a feeling this is subjective and too localised because this just depends on what each of us is used to, so I'm voting to close. However, trying setting the key to one you can press with a finger/thumb that is otherwise unused, or if your mouse has side buttons then use the 5-button mouse config. Failing that, maybe it's time to invest in a gamepad?

Comment: Won't post this as an answer as you specifically asked for keyboard buttons, but games like this (console oriented, as M'vy pointed out) are often best enjoyed with a gamepad, because more often than not the controls are designed around them. It'd be worth investing in one if you have trouble like this with other games, they're not too expensive.

Comment: I don't really feel like an optimal keyboard/mouse layout question is localized, exactly. The basic layout of a QWERTY keyboard and mouse aren't going to change anytime soon. Sure, I guess this is kind of subjective but not glaringly enough that I'm going to close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that a lot of *console oriented* games (which uses four controls buttons in addition to the keyboard) works nice with a multi-button mouse.

For AC2 specifically I have bound the **high-profile** to a button on the left of my mouse, **legs** to right-click, **main hand** to normal click, and **off-hand* to wheel-click. **Head** can be fairly affected to the keyboard as it is not of so much use.

This has the advantage of requiring me to concentrate on the movement keys on the keyboard (basically going forward, sometimes left and right movement) while having both high-profile and leg buttons pressed on the mouse. These buttons enable me to keep a nice grip and control over the mouse whenever I run.

For other games, I usually bind crouch, run, jump and other action on the keyboard. But usually they are not key you need to hold to much longer like in AC2, thus you don't have to worry about coordination too much or ghosting problems. But usually those games provides a better interface for customisation unlike AC-serie that enable you to customise 4 buttons and derive combinations with these.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. It looking interesting I am going to purchase a multi-buttons mouse :)